# Get number of current element in parent array object

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, jsx

I have the following JSON object and when in building the Message.jsx I would like to include as id the number of the current message element in the section array. How could I do that?

```
{   "sections": [
    {
      "message": {
        "from": "someone",
        "body": "ibsum"
      }
    },
    {
      "message": {
        "from": "someone else",
        "body": "lorem"
      }
    }, ...  ] }
```

Can I actually do this without explicitly setting an id property for each object in section array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the second property of `map` which is the element index within the array. You can set the key in the same way. Remember, indexes start from 0.

So something like this:

```
<Section>
{this.props.messages.map((message, i) => {
  return <Message key={i} id={i} info={message} />
})}
</Section>
```